# Java Bean :: How can you create a dynamically executed method (that can be re-adjusted)

Tags: java, spring, timer

I'm looking to create a bean that has the ability to execute some code every N minutes. This bean must be able to be adjusted (not just using @Scheduled(fixed=xxx) )

Synopsis

Worker Class

```
class Worker{

  @Autowired
  MyService myservice;

  myService.notifyUser(10);
}
```

Service Class

```
class MyService{

  public void notifyUser(int nMinutes){
       //Busy Code
  }
}
```

Comment: If you were upto to using some ejb, you would look at programmatic timers, otherwise you can also have a look at quartz which may help you adjust the execution time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask` Class

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
    //To run the task once you would do:
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              System.out.println("running Task..");
          }
        }, 5);

      // task repeat after the duration time you need to do like this
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Repeating running Task..");
        }
    }, 1*60*1000, 1*60*1000); // repeat after one minute
```

There is also TimerService see doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html)

Comment: I would use `TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)` for clarity